# What does “active” means on the user’s raised flags page?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I just saw that there’s a new “active” badge next to a “not an answer” flag I raised earlier today—what does it mean?

[image]

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190738/what-does-active-mean-in-my-flagging-summary-page

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The flag system is undergoing an overhaul of sorts - active means that the flag you have raised is active in the flag queue & hasn't been acted upon yet